# What is the Airport Shuttle logo meant to symbolize?

Tags: sets, stickers

The [Airport Shuttle set](https://brickset.com/sets/6399-1/Airport-Shuttle) features what is apparently supposed to be a logo of the Airport Shuttle monorail system, both on the train itself and prominently on top of the city stop (and possibly in more places). It looks like a capital letter **T** in front of a circle.

[image: photo of the logo in question]

**Is there any information available as to what this was meant to signify?** I.e. is it meant to symbolize anything about the set (a cross-section of the airport stop?), or is it modeled after a real-world symbol of a comparable transportation system?

Comment: I would have said it's the track and a stylised pillar, seen side on. A number of real-world monorails tend to include the track in their logos.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid That was my immediate reaction also, something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/fW3oqMi.png) perhaps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, here's a slightly enhanced, upclose image of the logo.
[image]
My best guess is that it's meant to represent a railway T-Intersection as seen below.

[image]
I believe this is especially possible, considering how the **T** tapers down to the bottom, similar to a railway T-Intersection.